# toDF is not a member of Seq ,toDS is not a member Seq

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I was trying to convert a sequence to dataframe or dataset with the below code .It seems to be pretty simple ,But I am getting exception while doing so .Not sure what mistake I have done .I tried to find out solution for the similar problem and as per that I moved my class definition outside of main , but still I am getting the issue.Below is the code

```
package sparkWCExample.spWCExample
      import org.apache.log4j.Level
      import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession , DataFrame , Row , Encoders }
      import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
      import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
      import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
      import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
      import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset



      // Create the case classes for our domain
case class Department(id: String, name: String)
case class Person(name: String, age: Long)


object DatasetExample  {
             def  main(args: Array[String]){
          println("Start now")
          val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Scala WordCount Example").setMaster("local[1]")
        val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).appName("CsvExample").master("local").getOrCreate()
        val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(spark.sparkContext)
        import sqlContext.implicits._
        import spark.implicits._

//val df = spark.read.options(Map("inferSchema"->"true","delimiter"->",","header"->"true")).csv("C:\\Sankha\\Study\\data\\salary.csv")

// Create the Departments
val department1 = new Department("123456", "Computer Science")
val department2 = new Department("789012", "Mechanical Engineering")
val department3 = new Department("345678", "Theater and Drama")
val department4 = new Department("901234", "Indoor Recreation")

val caseClassDS = Seq(Person("Andy", 32)).toDS()
val df = Seq(department1,department2,department3,department4).toDF



        }
}
```

I am using spark 2.4.5 and scala 2.12 and the above code was written in scala ide and below is the exception

toDF is not a member of Seq[sparkWCExample.spWCExample.Department
toDS is not a member of Seq[sparkWCExample.spWCExample.Person

Comment: What happen to your code? Indentation is really bad. Btw, this code is working in my environment. Please try with `spark` and you do not need to set the sqlContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Dataset, SparkSession}

// Create the case classes for our domain
case class Department(id: String, name: String)
case class Person(name: String, age: Long)

object DatasetExample {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Start now")
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Scala WordCount Example").setMaster("local[1]")
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).appName("CsvExample").master("local").getOrCreate()
    val sc: SparkContext = spark.sparkContext
    import spark.implicits._

    //val df = spark.read.options(Map("inferSchema"->"true","delimiter"->",","header"->"true")).csv("C:\\Sankha\\Study\\data\\salary.csv")

    // Create the Departments
    val department1 = Department("123456", "Computer Science")
    val department2 = Department("789012", "Mechanical Engineering")
    val department3 = Department("345678", "Theater and Drama")
    val department4 = Department("901234", "Indoor Recreation")

    val caseClassDS: Dataset[Person] = Seq(Person("Andy", 32)).toDS()
    val df: DataFrame = Seq(department1, department2, department3, department4).toDF

  }
}
```

You were using a deprecated Spark context and initialisation, also and had a lot of unused imports that I cleaned. 
The code itself is good, the only issue was in the spark context.

PS: I suggest you take a look at spark documentation for better understanding.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I used your code and it solved the problem .Thankss for your help .So just for better understanding deprecated spark context and initialisation was the problem ??

Instead of direct 
````spark.sparkContext````
It should be 
````val sc: SparkContext = spark.sparkContext````

That was the actual problem???Please advise